# javascript default value in Sql string

Tags: javascript, mysql

//I'm trying to add default vars too my sql string so I wont get a syntax error when my code loads. For some reason when i add the if statement it does nothing.

```
{`var serversLength = Request.Form("servers").count;
    var serversTemp = (serversLength) ? Request.Form("servers") : false;
    var servers = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= serversLength; i++) {
       servers.push(serversTemp(i));
    }
    var options = "";
    options +=  Request.Form("options");
    %> 

<%
    var dateLength = Request.Form("date").count;
    var dateTemp = (dateLength) ? Request.Form("date") : false;
    var date= [];
    for (i = 1; i <= dateLength; i++) {
       date.push(dateTemp(i));
    } %>
    <%
    var date2Length = Request.Form("date2").count;
    var date2Temp = (date2Length) ? Request.Form("date2") : false;
    var date2= []; 
    if (date2 === undefined){
    date2="9/29/2015";
    }
    for (i = 1; i <= date2Length; i++) {
       date2.push(date2Temp(i));
    } %>

  var SQL="SELECT LINKEDNAME, ERRNUM,CONVERT(CHAR(16),TSTAMP,21) AS TSTAMP, ERRDESC FROM MAIN.dbo.LINKEDSERVERFAILS " + ((serversLength) ? "WHERE LINKEDNAME IN ('" + servers.join("''") + "')" : "") + "AND TSTAMP BETWEEN" + ((dateLength) ? "('" + date.join("/ ") + "')" : "") + " AND " + ((date2Length) ? "('" + date2.join("/ ") + "')" : "") +""}
```

Comment: Can you also add the Error message you are receiving?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

date2 is an array, and you are assigning a string to your array, effectively overwriting it.

Instead, "push" the date inside the array with `date2.push("9/29/2015");`.

Also, when you do the `var date2 = [];`, date2 becomes an object, so it is not undefined anymore. Thus, the if clause will never be true.

Check for its length instead:

```
if (date2.length === 0){
    date2.push("9/29/2015");
}
```